# Service/Service (ServiceD69D759B) Resource timed out waiting for completion (RequestToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Our company has deployed the iot service based on the mqtt protocol before, and now the charging pile needs to support ocpp. I tried it according to the process you wrote, but something went wrong, please help me to take a look

When the following code is executed, an error is reported

```
npx cdk deploy
```

and the following is the error log.

```
AwsOcppGatewayStack | 10:19:35 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::Service                           | Service/Service (ServiceD69D759B) Resource timed out waiting for completion (RequestToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)

 ❌  AwsOcppGatewayStack failed: Error: The stack named AwsOcppGatewayStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource timed out waiting for completion (Requ
estToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)
    at FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:380:10236)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async deployStack2 (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:145775)
    at async E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:128776
    at async run (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:126782)

 ❌ Deployment failed: Error: Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named AwsOcppGatewayStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource timed out waitig for completion (RequestToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)
ng for completion (RequestToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)
    at deployStacks (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:129083)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async CdkToolkit.deploy (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:147824)
    at async exec4 (E:\MyAndroidProject\GitHub\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:438:51984)

Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named AwsOcppGatewayStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource timed out waiting for completion (RequestToken: 236aecf9-3036-3527-ad2e-213c52aed71e)
```

This is my current operating environment

```
System: Windows 10
docker: 20.10.17
npx: 8.11.0
cdk: 2.84.0
nodejs: 16.16.0
Operating environment: visual studio code terminal
```

By checking the cluster background log, I found that the following error has been reported

```
2023/6/19 GMT+8 14:36:17    /bin/sh: line 1: /opt/ocpp-gateway/run-server.sh: cannot execute: required file not found   dcf2ec0196064d8084f8df380c2b428e    Container
2023/6/19 GMT+8 14:35:07    /bin/sh: line 1: /opt/ocpp-gateway/run-server.sh: cannot execute: required file not found   d3e976899ed54c1991a2eef59ecd5007    Container
2023/6/19 GMT+8 14:33:58    /bin/sh: line 1: /opt/ocpp-gateway/run-server.sh: cannot execute: required file not found   7c850ac7430647019a28252c632374b7    Container
```

Comment: Your docker container is failing to start.

Comment: @gshpychka,  Thank you for reply, I integrated it through the documentation here on github [aws-ocpp-gateway](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ocpp-gateway), if the docker container fails to start, how should I troubleshoot it, can you provide some relevant ideas

Comment: Depends on your container. It's looking for some file and failing to find it, apparently.

Comment: @gshpychka, This is very strange. I also report this error when I run the docker image locally, but when I view the file through this command `docker run -it --platform linux/arm64 31342837934f /bin/bash`, run-server.sh is It is already in our container, and it is also the permission to execute

Comment: this is some screenshot of my local docker, [image1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTUSNX-yZ1FIdr9VxpbiNk_9e4S-IezZ/view?usp=drive_link) [iamge2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mndB6_m5vQxWvEzhMs5tXyMPvmZ9Nm23/view?usp=drive_link) [image3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OSPrypOZZdhSMPbtWbohSQ0pBfE4kAu2/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: If this error is also present locally, then this is not an AWS or CDK issue. I would edit the question/tags appropriately and provide the container source to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was a problem with the `run-server.sh` file format, the file edited under window would not be found in Linux, I used visual studio code, changed `CRLF` to `LF`, and the problem was solved